# I do not understand how to fix the error: "req.add"

Tags: solidity, chainlink, error, compiler

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT


pragma solidity 0.8.19;


import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";


contract RealEstateDataConsumer is ChainlinkClient {


    uint256 oraclePayment;
    uint256 public smartZipData;
    
    
    constructor(uint256 _oraclePayment) {
        
        setPublicChainlinkToken();
        oraclePayment = _oraclePayment;

    }


    function requestDataSmartZip(address _oracle, bytes32 _jobId, string memory _propertyId) public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        
        Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(_jobId, address(this), this.fulfillSmartZip.selector);
        req.add("property_id", _propertyId);
        return sendChainlinkRequestTo(_oracle, req, oraclePayment);
        
    }

    function fulfillSmartZip(bytes32 _requestId, uint256 _data) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId) {
        
        smartZipData = _data;
        
    }


}
```

The error message on the second line inside this function says,

```
Member "add" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in struct Chainlink.Request memory.
```

Comment: Can you include more code, like the whole file would be better, because this error can be derived from many problems.

Comment: I don't see `Chainlink.Request` as having a function `add` available to it anywhere. What are you expecting to happen, and where did you see that this function should be available on `Chainlink.Request`?

Comment: I have added the whole code.

Comment: @natewelch_ I copied this code from chainlink's website.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it resolved your issue, or comment if you need any further help...

Comment: Worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using library `Chainlink` for your `Chainlink.Request`, by adding this line to the beginning of your contract:

```
using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;
```

More information in the Chainlink [docs](https://docs.chain.link/any-api/get-request/examples/single-word-response/)